# I can't include python.h in omnet

Tags: python, c++, omnet++

I need to call a python function from my omnet++ project. I figured trying this https://www.coveros.com/calling-python-code-from-c/ . but when I include python.h I get the unresolved inclusion error. I have added the following path to file>properties> Paths and symbols: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if anyone has the same problem, I had added the path to the file's top directory. when I added it to the path and symbols of the same file that I wanted to call my python function from, it got fixed.